# Cannot update a component while rendering a different component warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am getting this warning in react:

```
index.js:1 Warning: Cannot update a component (`ConnectFunction`) 
while rendering a different component (`Register`). To locate the 
bad setState() call inside `Register`
```

I went to the locations indicated in the stack trace and removed all setstates but the warning still persists. Is it possible this could occur from redux dispatch?

my code:

register.js

```
class Register extends Component {
  render() {
    if( this.props.registerStatus === SUCCESS) { 
      // Reset register status to allow return to register page
      this.props.dispatch( resetRegisterStatus())  # THIS IS THE LINE THAT CAUSES THE ERROR ACCORDING TO THE STACK TRACE
      return <Redirect push to = {HOME}/>
    }
    return (
      <div style = {{paddingTop: "180px", background: 'radial-gradient(circle, rgba(106,103,103,1) 0%, rgba(36,36,36,1) 100%)', height: "100vh"}}>
        <RegistrationForm/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps( state ) {
  return {
    registerStatus: state.userReducer.registerStatus
  }
}

export default connect ( mapStateToProps ) ( Register );
```

function which triggers the warning in my registerForm component called by register.js

```
handleSubmit = async () => {
    if( this.isValidForm() ) { 
      const details = {
        "username": this.state.username,
        "password": this.state.password,
        "email": this.state.email,
        "clearance": this.state.clearance
      }
      await this.props.dispatch( register(details) )
      if( this.props.registerStatus !== SUCCESS && this.mounted ) {
        this.setState( {errorMsg: this.props.registerError})
        this.handleShowError()
      }
    }
    else {
      if( this.mounted ) {
        this.setState( {errorMsg: "Error - registration credentials are invalid!"} )
        this.handleShowError()
      }
    }
  }
```

Stacktrace:

[image: Stacktrace]

Comment: there's a big thread on it here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18178. are you able to post the stacktrace (not all of it, just the relevant parts) or tell us exactly the line it's referring to?

Comment: @RedBaron added the stacktrace

Comment: "There's nothing wrong with passing callbacks to children that update state in parents. That's always been fine." This was the most helpful answer for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71257867/470749

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I fixed this issue by removing the dispatch from the register components render method to the componentwillunmount method. This is because I wanted this logic to occur right before redirecting to the login page. In general it's best practice to put all your logic outside the render method so my code was just poorly written before. Hope this helps anyone else in future :)

My refactored register component:

```
class Register extends Component {

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Reset register status to allow return to register page
    if ( this.props.registerStatus !== "" ) this.props.dispatch( resetRegisterStatus() )
  }

  render() {
    if( this.props.registerStatus === SUCCESS ) { 
      return <Redirect push to = {LOGIN}/>
    }
    return (
      <div style = {{paddingTop: "180px", background: 'radial-gradient(circle, rgba(106,103,103,1) 0%, rgba(36,36,36,1) 100%)', height: "100vh"}}>
        <RegistrationForm/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you could also make some detructuring, e.g: ```const {someDispatch} = props;```, then use your dispatch wherever you want.

Answer (score 310):

This warning was introduced since React V16.3.0.

If you are using functional components you could wrap the setState call into useEffect.

Code that does not work:

```
const HomePage = (props) => {
    
  props.setAuthenticated(true);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    props.setSearchTerm(e.target.value.toLowerCase());
  };

  return (
    <div key={props.restInfo.storeId} className="container-fluid">
      <ProductList searchResults={props.searchResults} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now you can change it to:

```
const HomePage = (props) => {
  // trigger on component mount
  useEffect(() => {
    props.setAuthenticated(true);
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    props.setSearchTerm(e.target.value.toLowerCase());
  };

  return (
    <div key={props.restInfo.storeId} className="container-fluid">
      <ProductList searchResults={props.searchResults} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: And you should add second parameter ```[]``` to ```useEffect``` if you want this to run just once (not everytime state gets updated).

Comment: This fixed it for me. Now I'm trying to figure out why. Any help?

Comment: @sawyerrken [This link](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/02/26/react-v16.13.0.html#new-warnings) may answer part of the why, but overall, the issue continues to confuse me as I try to resolve the error.

Comment: In my case, I fixed by moving `dispatch` in  the `useEffect`

Comment: It's sometimes not possible to stick everything inside of a useEffect, i.e., when the state to set is the return of another hook (since you cant put hooks in useEffect).

Comment: can you elaborate on **why this works**?

Comment: this solution is great, but what if the parent state update method was used by multiple child components? in this case I will have to write useEffect in all of those child components. Is there a way to useEffect once among all those children? maybe inside the parent itself without having the child component worry about the "must-be-abstracted" inner details of the parent component?

Comment: @Normal & KenSawyerr -- does [Brett's answer help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62336340/cannot-update-a-component-while-rendering-a-different-component-warning#comment124536912_65911215)?

Comment: Wrapping in `useEffect` did it for me. Apparently the function (which included a `setState` in a superior component) was called more than once. Curiously, in my console there were two stack traces: one for this error, and immediately after it, a stack trace for the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Do not know how to serialize a BigInt` which was thrown out of the guts of `redux.js`. I've no idea why but the fix removed both errors.

Comment: @HamidShoja , your solution **worked for me**, I was using `dispatch` outside `useEffect` and it causing problem.

Comment: Wrapping in `useEffect` works, for the same reason you can't call `setState` directly in the render of its own component. If you pass the `setState` to a child component and call it there, that's exactly the same thing. When wrapped in `useEffect` it runs ***after*** component mount, not during render.

Answer (score 77):

I just had this issue and it took me a bit of digging around before I realised what I'd done wrong – I just wasn't paying attention to how I was writing my functional component.

I was doing this:

```
const LiveMatches = (props: LiveMatchesProps) => {
  const {
    dateMatches,
    draftingConfig,
    sportId,
    getDateMatches,
  } = props;

  if (!dateMatches) {
    const date = new Date();
    getDateMatches({ sportId, date });
  };

  return (<div>{component stuff here..}</div>);
};
```

I had just forgotten to use `useEffect` before dispatching my redux call of `getDateMatches()`

So it should have been:

```
const LiveMatches = (props: LiveMatchesProps) => {
  const {
    dateMatches,
    draftingConfig,
    sportId,
    getDateMatches,
  } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!dateMatches) {
      const date = new Date();
      getDateMatches({ sportId, date });
    }
  }, [dateMatches, getDateMatches, sportId]);

  return (<div>{component stuff here..}</div>);
};
```

Comment: How come putting your code into useEffect removes this warning?

Comment: @Plumpie because react works in 'cycles' it keeps track of what is rendered and when to update and render new components. It does this through the use of hooks or lifecycle methods. If this function is not inside the useEffect hook, then the component will attempt to call it on every rerender, and that also updates the component - out of order with what react would like. Moving the code into a hook, allows react to update components in the correct order so that it can keep track as things change.

Answer (score 72):

Please read the error message thoroughly. Mine was pointing to SignIn Component that had a bad setState. **I had an onPress that was not an Arrow function**.

It was like this:

```
onPress={navigation.navigate("Home", { screen: "HomeScreen" })}
```

I changed it to this:

```
onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home", { screen: "HomeScreen" }) }
```

My error message was:

> Warning: Cannot update a component
> (`ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer)`) while rendering a different
> component (`SignIn`). To locate the bad setState() call inside
> `SignIn`, follow the stack trace as described in
> https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render
> in SignIn (at SignInScreen.tsx:20)

Comment: This is what happened to me when I was coding feeling half sleepy. Thank you for saving me!

Comment: onPress={() => navigation. Navigate("HomeScreen") }

Comment: Why is the arrow function wrapper necessary?

Comment: @CamHart In simple terms, as mentioned in the error message, the cause is : updating the state of different components simultaneously.
the arrow function wrapper allows you to defer the execution of the navigation function until the button is pressed, avoiding conflicts and errors related to updating state during the rendering process.

Comment: @CamHart without it the `navigate` function is executed on render and the result is assigned as the `onPress` handler. With it a new function is assigned every render that *when called* executes `navigate` (and would return the result to the caller)

Answer (score 23):

I think that this is important.
It's from this [post](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18178) that @Red-Baron pointed out:

@machineghost : I think you're misunderstanding what the message is warning about.

There's nothing wrong with passing callbacks to children that update state in parents. That's always been fine.

The problem is when one component queues an update in another component, while the first component is rendering.

In other words, don't do this:

```
function SomeChildComponent(props) {
    props.updateSomething();
    return <div />
}
```

But this is fine:

```
function SomeChildComponent(props) {
    // or make a callback click handler and call it in there
    return <button onClick={props.updateSomething}>Click Me</button>
}
```

And, as Dan has pointed out various times, queuing an update in the same component while rendering is fine too:

```
function SomeChildComponent(props) {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);

  if(props.someValue > 10 && number < 5) {
    // queue an update while rendering, equivalent to getDerivedStateFromProps
    setNumber(42);
  }

  return <div>{number}</div>
}
```

Comment: In my case, I was using `useState` to store the callback, because the callback could change. Moving to `useCallback` instead fixed the problem

Answer (score 18):

If **`useEffect` cannot be used** in your case or if the error is **NOT because of Redux**

I used `setTimeout` to redirect one of the two `useState` variables to the callback queue.

I have one parent and one child component with `useState` variable in each of them. The solution is to wrap `useState` variable using `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(() => SetFilterData(data), 0);
```

**Example below**

**Parent Component**

```
import ExpenseFilter from '../ExpensesFilter'
    
function ExpensesView(props) {
    
    const [filterData, SetFilterData] = useState('')
    
    const GetFilterData = (data) => {
       // SetFilterData(data);

       //*****WRAP useState VARIABLE INSIDE setTimeout WITH 0 TIME AS BELOW.*****
       setTimeout(() => SetFilterData(data), 0);
    
    }
    
    const filteredArray = props.expense.filter(expenseFiltered => 
      expenseFiltered.dateSpent.getFullYear().toString() === filterData);
    
    
    return (
    <Window>
      <div>
        <ExpenseFilter FilterYear = {GetFilterData}></ExpenseFilter>
```

**Child Component**

```
const ExpensesFilter = (props) => {
    
    const [filterYear, SetFilterYear] = useState('2022')
    
    const FilterYearListener = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        SetFilterYear(event.target.value)
    }
    
    props.FilterYear(filterYear)
    
    return (
```

Comment: This works because `setTimeout()` is a blocking function forcing the `setFilterData` function to no longer be asynchronous. This is not how state hooks are meant to work and is basically a kluge that may result in unexpected behavior.

Comment: `setImmediate` would be a good alternative.

Comment: @DannyApostolov according to MDN setImmediate is non-standard and should not be used on production sites facing the web.

Comment: @hkiame sorry, I was thinking "react native" all the time... you're totally right!

Comment: @RyanNerd you made me suspect that this method is not the best, can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: UPDATE: WARNING!! this approach keeps calling the state forever, try to `console.log("called the state")` inside the `setTimeout` to see: ex: `setTimeout(() => {SetFilterData(data); console.log("called")}, 0);` // prints called 999.x times

Comment: @Normal A better approach is to have a `useEffect()` to capture changes to state and do the fetch and update inside: `useEffect(()=>{setFilterData(dataFromFetch)}, [props.expense.filter])` Assuming that `props.expense.filter` is the state change variable you want to monitor for changes.

Answer (score 6):

Using React and Material UI (MUI)
I changed my code **from:**

```
<IconButton onClick={setOpenDeleteDialog(false)}>
        <Close />
      </IconButton>
```

**To:**

```
<IconButton onClick={() => setOpenDeleteDialog(false)}>
        <Close />
      </IconButton>
```

Simple fix

Comment: I had a similar, I had an event that I was wrongly attaching a function.

Comment: Just a "me too" here, I was executing the handler during the render instead of assigning it.  In my case I was doing something like this: <button onClick={props.onCancel()} /> instead of <button onClick={props.onCancel} />.

Answer (score 5):

If you use **React Navigation** and you are using the `setParams` or `setOptions` you must put these inside method `componentDidMount()` of class components or in `useEffects()` hook of functional components.

Answer (score 4):

Cannot update a component while rendering a different component warning

I have the same problem but when I dispatch an action inside a component rendered. You should dispatch the action inside useEffect hook  to fix that problem

---

```
//dispatch action to inform user that 'Marked days already have hours!'
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (btn_class == 'redButton') {
      dispatch({ type: ActionType.ADD_NOTIFICATION, payload: 'Marked days already have hours!' });
    } else {
      dispatch({ type: ActionType.ADD_NOTIFICATION, payload: '' });
    }
  }, [btn_class, dispatch]);
```

---

also use union type for btn-class variable
*`

```
type ButtonState = 'btnAddDay' | 'redButton' | 'btnAddDayBlue' | 'btnAddDayGreen';
```

`*

Answer (score 3):

**Minimal reproducing example**

I was a bit confused as to what exactly triggers the problem, having a minimal immediately runnable example helped me grasp it a little better:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.14.7/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
function NotMain(props) {
  props.setN(1)
  return <div>NotMain</div>
}

function Main(props) {
  const [n, setN] = React.useState(0)
  return <>
    <NotMain setN={setN} />
    <div>Main {n}</div>
  </>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Main/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

fails with error:

> react-dom.development.js:61 Warning: Cannot update a component (`Main`) while rendering a different component (`NotMain`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `NotMain`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render

followed by a stack trace:

```
    at NotMain (<anonymous>:16:9)
    at Main (<anonymous>:21:31)
```

Presumably 16:9 would be the exact line where `props.setN(1)` is being called from, but the line numbers are a bit messed up because of the Babel JSX translation.

The solution like many other answers said is to do instead:

```
function NotMain(props) {
  React.useEffect(() => { props.setN(1) }, [])
  return <div>NotMain</div>
}
```

Intuitively, I think that the general idea of why this error happens is that:

> You are not supposed to updat state from render methods, otherwise it could lead to different results depending on internal the ordering of how React renders things.

and when using functional components, the way to do that is to use hooks. In our case, `useEffect` will run after rendering is done, so we are fine doing that from there.

When using classes this becomes slightly more clear and had been asked for example at:

- [Calling setState in render is not avoidable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290245/calling-setstate-in-render-is-not-avoidable)
- [Calling setState() in React from render method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226268/calling-setstate-in-react-from-render-method/52024407)

When using functional components however, things are conceptually a bit more mixed, as the component function is both the render, and the code that sets up the callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this after coming across a similar question in GitHub which led me to [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18178#issuecomment-595846312) showing how to pinpoint the exact line within your file causing the error. I wasn't aware that the stack trace was there. Hopefully this helps someone!

See below for my fix. I simply converted the function to use callback.

Old code

```
function TopMenuItems() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  function mountProjectListToReduxStore(projects) {
    const projectDropdown = projects.map((project) => ({
      id: project.id,
      name: project.name,
      organizationId: project.organizationId,
      createdOn: project.createdOn,
      lastModifiedOn: project.lastModifiedOn,
      isComplete: project.isComplete,
    }));
    projectDropdown.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
    dispatch(loadProjectsList(projectDropdown));
    dispatch(setCurrentOrganizationId(projectDropdown[0].organizationId));
  }
};
```

New code

```
function TopMenuItems() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const mountProjectListToReduxStore = useCallback((projects) => {
    const projectDropdown = projects.map((project) => ({
      id: project.id,
      name: project.name,
      organizationId: project.organizationId,
      createdOn: project.createdOn,
      lastModifiedOn: project.lastModifiedOn,
      isComplete: project.isComplete,
    }));
    projectDropdown.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
    dispatch(loadProjectsList(projectDropdown));
    dispatch(setCurrentOrganizationId(projectDropdown[0].organizationId));
  }, [dispatch]);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

My case was using `setState` callback, instead of `setState` + `useEffect`

**BAD ❌**

```
  const closePopover = useCallback(
    () =>
      setOpen((prevOpen) => {
        prevOpen && onOpenChange(false);
        return false;
      }),
    [onOpenChange]
  );
```

**GOOD ✅**

```
  const closePopover = useCallback(() => setOpen(false), []);

  useEffect(() => onOpenChange(isOpen), [isOpen, onOpenChange]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue, The fix worked for me was if u are doing

> setParams/setOptions

outside of useEffect then this issue is occurring. So try to do such things inside useEffect. It'll work like charm

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR;**
For my case, what I did to fix the warning was to change from `useState` to `useRef`

```
react_devtools_backend.js:2574 Warning: Cannot update a component (`Index`) while rendering a different component (`Router.Consumer`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Router.Consumer`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render
    at Route (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:126692:29)
    at Index (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:144246:25)
    at Switch (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:126894:29)
    at Suspense
    at App
    at AuthProvider (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:144525:23)
    at ErrorBoundary (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:21030:87)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:126327:30)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:125948:35)
    at QueryClientProvider (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:124450:21)
```

The full code for the context of what I did (changed from the lines with `// OLD:` to the line above them). However **this doesn't matter, just try changing from `useState` to `useRef`!!**

```
import { HOME_PATH, LOGIN_PATH } from '@/constants';
import { NotFoundComponent } from '@/routes';
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route, RouteProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAccess } from '@/access';
import { useAuthContext } from '@/contexts/AuthContext';
import { AccessLevel } from '@/models';

type Props = RouteProps & {
  component: Exclude<RouteProps['component'], undefined>;
  requireAccess: AccessLevel | undefined;
};

export const Index: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const { component: Component, requireAccess, ...rest } = props;

  const { isLoading, isAuth } = useAuthContext();
  const access = useAccess();
  const mounted = React.useRef(false);
  // OLD: const [mounted, setMounted] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        // If in indentifying authentication state as the page initially loads, render a blank page
        if (!mounted.current && isLoading) return null;
        // OLD: if (!mounted && isLoading) return null;

        // 1. Check Authentication is one step
        if (!isAuth && window.location.pathname !== LOGIN_PATH)
          return <Redirect to={LOGIN_PATH} />;
        if (isAuth && window.location.pathname === LOGIN_PATH)
          return <Redirect to={HOME_PATH} />;

        // 2. Authorization is another
        if (requireAccess && !access[requireAccess])
          return <NotFoundComponent />;

        mounted.current = true;
        // OLD: setMounted(true);
        return <Component {...props} />;
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default Index;
```

Comment: I believe setting `ref.current=` will not cause a rerender. Could be an issue because `setState` is primarly used for rerendering with new state.

Answer (score 1):

My example.

Code with that error:

```
<Form
    initialValues={{ ...kgFormValues, dataflow: dataflows.length > 0 ? dataflows[0].df_tpl_key : "" }}
    onSubmit={() => {}}
    render={({values, dirtyFields }: any) => {
      
      const kgFormValuesUpdated = {
        proj_key: projectKey,
        name: values.name,
        description: values.description,
        public: values.public,
        dataflow: values.dataflow,
        flavours: flavoursSelected,
        skipOCR: values.skipOCR
      };

      if (!_.isEqual(kgFormValues, kgFormValuesUpdated)) {
        setNewKgFormValues(kgFormValuesUpdated);
      }
```

Working Code:

```
 <Form
    initialValues={{ ...kgFormValues, dataflow: dataflows.length > 0 ? dataflows[0].df_tpl_key : "" }}
    onSubmit={() => {}}
    render={({ values, dirtyFields }: any) => {
      useEffect(() => {
        const kgFormValuesUpdated = {
          proj_key: projectKey,
          name: values.name,
          description: values.description,
          public: values.public,
          dataflow: values.dataflow,
          flavours: flavoursSelected,
          skipOCR: values.skipOCR
        };

        if (!_.isEqual(kgFormValues, kgFormValuesUpdated)) {
          setNewKgFormValues(kgFormValuesUpdated);
        }
      }, [values]);

      return (
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I was setting some state that was storing a function like so:

```
// my state definition
const [onConfirm, setOnConfirm] = useState<() => void>();

// then I used this piece of code to update the state
function show(onConfirm: () => void) {
    setOnConfirm(onConfirm);
}
```

The problem was from setOnConfirm. In React, setState can take the new value OR a function that returns the new value. In this case React wanted to get the new state from calling onConfirm which is not correct.

changing to this resolved my issue:

```
setOnConfirm(() => onConfirm);
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue. The cause of the error was the "useLocation()" hook of react-router-dom. I have moved it to before of the "return <Navigate to ..." then it was fixed.

I don't know what was changed but it worked. If anybody could explain this, I will be glad...

My old code is:

```
import { Navigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';


export const Navigation = ({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren): JSX.Element => {

    const location = useLocation(); //  ---> Cause of the error

    if (Authenticator.isAuthenticated() && window.sessionStorage.getItem('isAuthenticated') === 'true') {
      return <>{children}</>;
    }


    return <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} replace />;
  };
```

Correct version is:

```
export const Navigation = ({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren): JSX.Element => {
    if (Authenticator.isAuthenticated() && window.sessionStorage.getItem('isAuthenticated') === 'true') {
      return <>{children}</>;
    }

    const location = useLocation(); // moved here and fixed

    return <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} replace />;
  };
```

My given error was:

```bash
Warning: Cannot update a component (`Header`) while rendering a different 
component (`Unknown`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Unknown`, 
follow the stack trace as described in 
https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render
    at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:251:5
    at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:60935:5)
    at Outlet (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:61419:26)
    at aside
    at section
    at Drawer
```

Answer (score 1):

### How I solved it:

As @ADTC mentions in his answer:

> This is clearly one of those problems where the correct solution depends on the context in which the problem occurs.

My Problem/Context:

```
'use client';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

enum Role {
  Admin = 'admin',
  Client = 'client',
}

const Page = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [role, setRole] = useState<Role | undefined>(undefined);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  if(role) {           // <--------------  Problem: React doesn't like this approach
    switch (role) {
      case Role.Admin:
        router.push('/admin');
        return;
      case Role.Client:
        router.push('/client');
        return;
    }
  }

  return (
      <main>
          <form
            onSubmit={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              if (username === Role.Admin && password === Role.Admin) return setRole(Role.Admin);
              return setRole(Role.Client);
            }}
          >
            <input
              onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.currentTarget.value)}
              placeholder="Username"
            />
            <input
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.currentTarget.value)}
              placeholder="Password"
            />
            <button type="submit">
              Login
            </button>
          </form>
      </main>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

### Solved with useEffect

```
'use client';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

enum Role {
  Admin = 'admin',
  Client = 'client',
}

const Page = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [role, setRole] = useState<Role | undefined>(undefined);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {      // <--------------  Solution: use useEffect
    if (!role) return;
    switch (role) {
      case Role.Admin:
        router.push('/admin');
        return;
      case Role.Client:
        router.push('/client');
        return;
    }
  }, [role]);

  return (
      <main>
          <form
            onSubmit={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              if (username === Role.Admin && password === Role.Admin) return setRole(Role.Admin);
              return setRole(Role.Client);
            }}
          >
            <input
              onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.currentTarget.value)}
              placeholder="Username"
            />
            <input
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.currentTarget.value)}
              placeholder="Password"
            />
            <button type="submit">
              Login
            </button>
          </form>
      </main>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

The useEffect will in this case be triggered whenever the [role] value is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I got this when I was foolishly invoking a function that called dispatch instead of passing a reference to it for onClick on a button.

```
  const quantityChangeHandler = (direction) => {
    dispatch(cartActions.changeItemQuantity({title, quantityChange: direction}));
  }
...
          <button onClick={() => quantityChangeHandler(-1)}>-</button>
          <button onClick={() => quantityChangeHandler(1)}>+</button>
```

Initially, I was directly calling without the fat arrow wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue when using `navigate` directly inside an if statement. After I change it to `Navigate`, the warning is resolved

Before

```
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
const navigate = useNavigate();

if (!shouldShow()) {
    navigate("/abc");
    return null;
}
```

After

```
import {Navigate} from 'react-router-dom';

if (!shouldShow()) {
    return <Navigate to="/abc" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly one of those problems where the correct solution depends on the context in which the problem occurs.

My context is completely different from the rest of the answers, hence this answer. Here's my context:

- I'm using Next.js 14, though this is also applicable to Next.js 13.
- I'm using an "App Router" setup.
- I'm using the `useRouter` hook in a client component.

In my case, originally it was something like this simple example:

```
'use client';

import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

export default function Component({ check }: { check: boolean }) {
  const router = useRouter();

  if (check) router.push('/some/path');       // <-- problem line

  return <div>My Component</div>
}
```

The problem is, (for this example) when `check` is true, `router.push` activates, but **also** the component returns `<div>My Component</div>`. It looks like React doesn't like this. You should not push the router ***and*** return a `JSX.Element` at the same time.

The fix is simple. Return immediately after `router.push`:

```
  ...

  if (check) {
    router.push('/some/path');
    return;
  }

  ...
```

This ensures the component returns early and won't return the `JSX.Element` if it's also pushing the router.

**Note 1:** You cannot do `return router.push('/some/path')` as the `void` type cannot be assigned to `Element`. `return;` by itself returns `undefined` which is compatible with `Element`.

**Note 2:** This error may only occur if your component is returning some complex nesting of child components. The above simple return of `<div>My Component</div>` is for illustration purposes only. However, it's safer to always include `return;` after `router.push` even if your component's `JSX.Element` return is simple.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was trying to update state while setting another state.

BAD ❌

```
const handleClick = async (event: MouseEvent, choice: string) => {
    setUserSelections((prev) => {
      if (multiple_select) {
        let newSelected = null;
    if (prev.includes(choice)) {
      newSelected = prev.filter((item) => item !== choice);
    } else {
      newSelected = [...prev, choice];
    }
        setTmpAnswer({
      text: newSelected,
      options: options,
      question: questionText
    });
        return newSelected;
      } else {
        setAnswer({
          text: choice,
          options: options,
          question: questionText
        });
    return [choice];
      }
    });
  };
```

In this above code you can see that i was trying to setTmpAnswer which is itself a state inside another setState -> `setUserSelections`. I figured it out that you get this warning when you are trying to setState during rendering phase. In this case as you can see while calling `setUserSelection` we were in rendering phase and i was trying to setTmpAnswer which is another useState passed as prop from parent component. Here is how i fixed it.

GOOD ✅

```
const handleClick = async (event: MouseEvent, choice: string) => {
  let newSelected;
  if (multiple_select) {
    setUserSelections((prev) => {
      newSelected = prev.includes(choice)
        ? prev.filter((item) => item !== choice)
        : [...prev, choice];
      return newSelected;
    });
    setTmpAnswer({
      text: newSelected,
      options: options,
      question: questionText,
    });
  } else {
    setAnswer({
      text: choice,
      options: options,
      question: questionText,
    });
    setUserSelections([choice]);
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Using some of the answers above, i got rid of the error with the following:

**from**

```
if (value === "newest") {
  dispatch(sortArticlesNewest());
} else {
  dispatch(sortArticlesOldest());
}
```

> this code was on my component top-level

**to**

```
    const SelectSorting = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const {value, onChange} = useSelect();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (value === "newest") {
      dispatch(sortArticlesNewest());
    } else {
      dispatch(sortArticlesOldest());
    }
  }, [dispatch, value]);
```