# how to call the reducer action inside hook function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have one reducer that includes two actions, one is set up some state `shouldUpdateTime` to true/false and the other action is reset the state to initialState as false
I would like to call the action `resetShouldUpdateTime` under hook `useUpdateTime` after some api request triggered

I think I cannt mutate the state inside the hook function but how can I do it?

```
//clockReducers
interface ReducerValue {
  shouldUpdateTime: boolean;
}

export const initialState: ReducerValue = {
  shouldUpdateTime: false,
};

export const clockSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'clock',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setShouldUpdateTime: (state: ReducerValue, action: PayloadAction<boolean>) => {
      return {...state, shouldUpdateTime: action.payload};
    },

    resetShouldUpdateTime: (state: ReducerValue) => {
      return {...state, shouldUpdateTime: false};
    },
  },
});

export const {
  setShouldUpdateTime
} = clockSlice.actions;

export const clockReducer = clockSlice.reducer;

// middleware for updateTime
const updateTimeMiddleware = (action: AnyAction): AppThunk => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const prevTime = getState()?.unitTime || {};
    dispatch(action)
    const newTime = getState()?.unitTime || {};
    dispatch(setShouldUpdateTime(prevTime > newTime));
  };
};

// hook
function useUpdateTime(){
  const shouldUpdateTime = useSelector(
    (state: AppState) => state.clockReducer.shouldUpdateTime
  );
  ... do some api request
  // I would like to call resetShouldUpdateTime action to set shouldUpdateTime state to false
}


export default function App() {
  const onClickHandler = useCallBack(() =>{
    useDispatch(updateTimeMiddleware(someAction))
  })
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={onClickHandler}>Hello CodeSandbox</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: See https://dev.to/jenkens/react-redux-with-hooks-2ie1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom hook you can get a reference to the Redux store's dispatch function with [useDispatch](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch).

The object returned from [createSlice](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createslice#return-value) looks like

```
{
    name : string,
    reducer : ReducerFunction,
    actions : Record<string, ActionCreator>,
    caseReducers: Record<string, CaseReducer>
}
```

> Each function defined in the reducers argument will have a corresponding action creator generated using createAction and included in the result's actions field using the same function name.

So you can use the store's dispatch function together with the `resetShouldUpdateTime` action like this:

```
function useUpdateTime() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  //... do some api request
  // I would like to call resetShouldUpdateTime action to set shouldUpdateTime state to false
  dispatch(clockSlice.actions.resetShouldUpdateTime());
}
```

Comment: hm...i have tried it but it is the error I got `Warning: Cannot update a component (`xxx`) while rendering a different component (`yyyyy`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `yyyy``

Comment: Perhaps you should add a link to your CodeSandbox to the question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62336340/cannot-update-a-component-while-rendering-a-different-component-warning