# Why is this warning showing? I can't understand. How can I solve this?

Tags: reactjs

Warning: Cannot update a component (`BrowserRouter`) while rendering a different component (`Login`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Login`

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62336340/cannot-update-a-component-while-rendering-a-different-component-warning

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.