# ReactJs Login/authentication

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have an application in ReactJs where I am trying to navigate to the dashboard after successfully authenticating. Still, I don't understand why it doesn't advance to the next page only after reloading the page.

I reproduced my code in a sandbox for a better understanding.

https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-snow-j2etkj?file=/src/App.js

[image]

Comment: As per your codesandbox, it is working perfectly fine. I don't understand what's the issue here ?

Comment: Well, in this console it doesn't show, but in the browser, I get a horrible error and sometimes it crashes.  (I updated the image in the question)

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar error received in this stack overflow question -->
[Cannot update a component while rendering a different component warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62336340/cannot-update-a-component-while-rendering-a-different-component-warning)

So the answer was that you were setting the state in a component which was rendering multiple times.
So the setstate was called multiple times.

The setstate had to be wrapper in a useEffect hook to fix the error so that it is called only once.