# Next.js RTK SSR Auth inside App.getInitialProps cause error when navigate: Cannot update a component X while rendering a different component (`App`)

Tags: redux, next.js, redux-toolkit, rtk-query, next-redux-wrapper

When I implemented the logic of fetching the authenticated user and setting it to the Redux state inside the `App.getInitialProps` method and accessing that user from the state within any Next.js page, I encountered an error when navigating between pages.

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`HomeScreen`) while rendering a different component (`App`).
```

[image: an error that occurs when I navigating between pages]

```js
...
export const HomeScreen = () => {
  const user = useAppSelector(selectCurrentUser);
  ...
```

Here is the problem. Inside `App.getInitialProps` I'm fetching the API endpoint using RTK Query to retrieve the auth user from the cookie and when the query is fulfilled user adds to the state. And that causes that error in the console.

```js
// _app.tsx

import '@/assets/styles/globals.scss';

import type { NextPage } from 'next';
import type { AppContext, AppProps } from 'next/app';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import { wrapper } from '@/store';
import { me } from '@/store/auth/auth.api';

export type NextPageWithLayout<P = {}, IP = P> = NextPage<P, IP> & {
  getLayout?: (page: React.ReactElement) => React.ReactNode;
};

type AppPropsWithLayout = AppProps & {
  Component: NextPageWithLayout;
};

function App({ Component, ...rest }: AppPropsWithLayout) {
  const {
    store,
    props: { pageProps },
  } = wrapper.useWrappedStore(rest);

  const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => page);

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>{getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}</Provider>
  );
}

App.getInitialProps = wrapper.getInitialAppProps(
  (store) =>
    async ({ ctx, Component }: AppContext) => {
      // That string causes the error
      await store.dispatch(me.initiate());
      return {
        pageProps: {
          ...(Component.getInitialProps
            ? await Component.getInitialProps({ ...ctx, store })
            : {}),
        },
      };
    },
);

export default App;
```

The query that I initiate inside App.getInitialProps:

```js
me: builder.query<User, void>({
      query: () => ({
        url: 'auth/me',
        method: 'GET',
      }),
      async onQueryStarted(_args, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
        try {
          const { data } = await queryFulfilled;
          dispatch(setCredentials({ user: data }));
        } catch (err) {
          // Do nothing
        }
      },
    }),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot update a component while rendering a different component warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62336340/cannot-update-a-component-while-rendering-a-different-component-warning)

Comment: @AhmedSbai And how do you think It can help with my case? Answers there are not related to my case